# Update IN MYSQL InnoDB million records

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-performance

MYSQL Innodb Update Issue:

Once I receive a response (status) for a record ,I need to update the response to a very large table (Approximate 1 million records and will keep increasing),and this will keep happen may be 100 times per second. May I know will there any performance issue? OR any setting I can modify to avoid table locking or query slowing issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to **accept** the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a design issue.

Instead storing the flag (which the status-record update changes) for million data-records, you should store a reference in data-records pointing to the status-record. So, when you update the status-record, no further db operation required. Also, when you're scanning through the data-records, you should JOIN for the status-records (if it's needed to display). If status-record change occurs often, it's better than update millions of data-records.

Maybe, I'm wrong, you should explain the db (structure, table record counts) for more accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your table using the MyISAM storage engine, then your table will [lock with every update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

However, the InnoDB storage engine is capable of [locking individual rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-storage-engine.html).

If you need to `UPDATE` multiple records simultaneously, InnoDB may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Any indexes you have on the database (especially clustered indexes) will slow your writes down.

Indexes speed up reading, but they slow down writing.  Most databases get read more than written to, but it sounds like yours gets written to much more.